# Pager of jqgrid not visible in my mvc application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I have a jqgrid

```
<div>
        <div >
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="tblJQGridCCVT"></table>
        </div>
</div>

$("#tblJQGridCCVT").jqGrid(
            {
                url: "@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")" + "?Parameters=" + Params + "",
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                colNames: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E','F', so on...],//nearly 30 columns
                colModel: [
                {
                    name: 'A', index: 'A', width: 150, edittype: 'select', formatter: linkFmatter
                },
            { name: 'B', index: 'B', width: 150 },
            { name: 'C', index: 'C', width: 150 },
            { name: 'D', index: 'Updated By', width: 150 },
            { name: 'E', index: 'E', width: 150 },
            { name: 'F', index: 'F', width: 150 },
            So on 
            ...
            ...
            ...
                ],
                pager: $('#pager'),
                height:300,
                rowNum: 10,
                sortorder: "desc",
                sortname: 'ResponseId',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortable: true,
                loadonce: true, forceClientSorting: true,
                ignoreCase: true,
                caption: "Summary"
            });
            $("#tblJQGridCCVT").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { view: false, del: false, add: false, edit: false, search: true, refreshtext: "Refresh" }, { closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true, closeAfterSearch: true }, {}, {}, {});
            $("#tblJQGridCCVT").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn' });
```

As you can see i am loading the entire grid at once by using 'loadonce: true'
I am Unable to find either paging controls or serach controls of the jqgrid.

can some one tell me if there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). The option `forceClientSorting: true`, which you use exist only in **free jqGrid**. Free jqGrid supports Boolean value for the `pager` parameter. Thus you can fix your problem in free jqGrid by replacing `pager: $('#pager')` to `pager: true`. You included [mvcjqgrid](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mvcjqgrid/info) tag to your question, which means *another product. What you use?

Comment: You should add <div id="pager"></div> div element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the div of pagination with the same id check this tutorial :
[enter link description here](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)